# Spring boot aggregation with group Trim

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate

Consider collection with whitespace in field, in DB if there is white space if we group them "Ravi", " Ravi " , consider as total 2 values. but it should consider as single value. So I have trim in Group. I had performed in DB. But I don't know how can I trim and group value in Springboot. We can use Aggregation for this in Springboot. but don't how to use trim. Kindly help on this

Sample Collection:

```
 [
      {
        "name": "ravi",
        "DOB": "04-02-2000",
        "Blood": "A1+"
      },
      {
        "name": "ravi ",
        "DOB": "05-03-2000",
        "Blood": "A1+"
      },
      {
        "name": "kumar ",
        "DOB": "02-04-2000",
        "Blood": "A1+"
      },
      {
        "name": "kumar",
        "DOB": "03-05-2000",
        "Blood": "A1+"
      }
    ]
```

MongoDB Operation:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$group": {
    _id: {
      $trim: {
        input: "$name"
      }
    },
    doc: {
      "$first": "$$ROOT",
      
    }
  }
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$doc"
  }
})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Blood": "A1+",
    "DOB": "04-02-2000",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "name": "ravi"
  },
  {
    "Blood": "A1+",
    "DOB": "02-04-2000",
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000002"),
    "name": "kumar "
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide examples of what you want to do

Comment: Pls find updated question @IlyaSazonov

Comment: Have you tried using https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/StringOperators.Trim.html ? Or you have questions how to use Aggregation ?

Comment: I tried using Stringoperators.trim but I get error like Type aggeration is not applicable for SpringOperator. I used like group(Trim.value(Fieldname)). I wanted to know how can I use trim operation in aggeration

Comment: "$group": {
    _id: {
      $trim: {
        input: "$name"
      }
    },
    doc: {
      "$first": "$$ROOT",
      
    }
  }
}  -- > Convert this into java Springboot code @IlyaSazonov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Not possible via standard API.

**Workaround:** We need to add extra `$addFields` to trim the `name` field before applying `$group` stage.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate template;
...

Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.addFields()
       .addFieldWithValue("name", Trim.valueOf("name")).build(),       
    Aggregation.group("name")
        .first("$$ROOT").as("doc"),
    Aggregation.replaceRoot("doc")
);

...
template.aggregate(agg, inputType, outputType);
```

**Note:** Since you were manipulating the `name` field in the first stage, MongoDB wouldn't use indexes, so we can add an extra stage to the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks@Valijon
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.addFields()
       .addFieldWithValue("name", Trim.valueOf("name")).build(),       
    Aggregation.group("name")
        .first("$$ROOT").as("doc").count().as("Total"),
    Aggregation.replaceRoot("doc")
);

Here we store the count in String variable "Total", How can we get the value of count in interger format?

Comment: @hodophiler Not exactly, `Total` is the variable name, `.count()` returns Integer. Since you are replacing the root document with `$doc`, it's gone... Try to `$addFields` the Total field before replaceRoot and you will get the desired result